# Determine the line integral of a region of the sphere.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the curve $\alpha$ given in the following image

[image: given curve]

It is the unit sphere of radius 1 centered at the origin. We want to calculate $\oint f \cdot d\alpha$ where $f(x, y, z)=x, y, z$

Clearly the initial step is to parameterize the curve $\alpha$, as far as I can interpret I must parameterize a portion of the sphere, my attempt to parameterize was as follows.

We have to $x(\phi, \theta)=\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$, $y(\phi, \theta)=\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$ and $z(\phi, \theta)=\cos(\phi)$, from where $0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\phi}{2}$ and $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\phi}{2}$ with this a possible parameterization is $\alpha(u, t)=(\sin(u)\cos(t), \sin(u)\sin(t), \cos(u))$ from where $\alpha:[0, \frac{\phi}{2}]$

Then it would simply be to use the line integral definition and replace the values of the parameterization; but it is precisely the latter that is not clear to me, I do not know if the above is correct, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you noticed that $f(x,y,z)=\vec{\nabla}\big(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}\big)$?

Comment: @MatthewH. I understand that there is a theorem that says that if $\alpha$ is a closed curve then $\int \nabla  f \cdot d\alpha=0$, you mean I can use something like that? I don't understand the gradient hint very well.

Comment: Put very loosely, if $f=\vec{\nabla}g$ for some scalar valued function $g$, and if a $\mathcal{C}$ is a smooth curve connecting $P$ and $Q$ (in that order), then $\int_{\mathcal{C}}(f\cdot T)\mathrm{d}s=g(Q)-g(P)$. This is the fundamental theorem of line integrals. Your curve is closed, so $P=Q$ making your integral $0$.

Comment: @MatthewH. What a subtle, great help!